Why "contained" as a past form is not correct here?

Canada's constitution, enacted in 1982, contains just one of the six constitutional features that enhance judicial independence, as identified by legal scholars Sarah Bennett and David Thompson. After 1990, such de jure judicial independence became more prevalent, as exemplified in Mexico's constitution, enacted in 1994 and ______ four of these features.

Which choice completes the text so that it conforms to the conventions of Standard English?
A) contained
B) had contained
C) contains
D) containing
The key I have for the question above is "D".
But how come a participle "containing" can be grammatically correct?
IMO I would choose A, as an active verb in past form.

After a careful contemplation, my take on this is as below:
We have a complete sentence "such de jure judicial independence became more prevalent".
The following "as exemplified..." is just a dependent clause.
Options A,B,C if chosen, will make the dependent clause become an independent one as having a main verb, thus creating a comma splice.
Only D keeps it as a dependent clause.

Please stop answering in comments. Write an answer in the answer box and (if necessary) ask for clarification there.

I can't flag this as a duplicate but see this and the linked questions; they run back to this which is kind of a duplicate but not terribly obvious.

@Apple Your answer appears to be an answer: please write it in the Answer box. Others can upvote it if they agree, or write another answer if they don't. The system really doesn't like unanswered questions and will bump them periodically so they might get an answer.

[Maybe I'll answer it myself.]

There needs to be parallelism. In the string in question:

... as exemplified in Mexico's constitution,

enacted in 1994

and

______ four of these features.


The two post-modifiers (of the NP 'Mexico's constitution') are
'enacted in 1994' (some would imagine a deleted 'which was' or 'which had been' here)
and
'containing four of these features'.
To demonstrate that the ing-form is the only acceptable choice, simplify to

'There was a gift on the table, {or :} a tin contained / had contained / contains / containing delicious mince pies'.

Both -ed forms and -ing forms can be used to modify NPs

a box containing chocolates [= 'which contains or contained']
a lion contained in the cage [= 'which is/was contained']

(and indeed there is one of each here)
but the -ed form 'contained', equivalent to 'which is/was contained', does not work here, and would require say a prepositional phrase (eg 'contained in the agreement').

The constitution was enacted in 1994, and contained four features. Presumably it's still in force, so it still contains (present tense) them. The gerund acts like an adjective; it's a constitution containing four features.

OK, a participle - though some grammarians don't distinguish between them.

The coordinated subordinate clauses must both be non-finite.
